# Animate outline with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to draw attention to a particular table row but putting an outline around it.

I can add it like this:

```
$("#myTable tr:last-child").css("outline", "#c00 solid 2px");
```

But I would like to fade this outline in first and after a few seconds fade it out.

I know there's an .animate() function but I can't figure out how to incorporate it in this case.

Comment: you might be able to animate the width, but i don't think you can animate the opacity of an outline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery ui's [addClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/). This way just make the border a class and then give it a duration

```
$("#myTable tr:last-child").addClass( "outline", 1000);
```

Set a timeout then remove the class the same way.

Answer (score 0):

[jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) should fit your needs.

```
<div style="outline: solid 10px rgba(255,0,0,0)" />

$("div").animate({
    outlineColor: "rgba(255, 255, 0, 1.0)" 
}, 5000);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwvft/)